# How do I change the PWM frequency on an Arduino Uno

Tags: c++, timer

I currently trying to change the PWM frequency from the the standard 490 Hz to something else, Literally something else.

I previously used a `timer1` library available from the Arduino, but became annoyed by it an began setting up things manually.

```
#include "test.h"

test::test()
{
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  //Timer1 setup1 Interrup at 1hz
  cli(); // Stop interrupts
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1A = 15624; // Compare register value = cpu_fre/(interrupt_freq*prescaler)-1 (must be <65536)
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12)| (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10); 
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

  sei(); //allow interrupts
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
 digitalWrite(10,!digitalRead(10));
}
```

here is the main

```
#include "test.h"

test test1;

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(230400);   
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

This should should create an interrupt each 1 Hz changing the state of the pin.  but instead creates a 490 Hz PWM signal...

Changing the prescaler or OCR1A only changes the duty cycle of the signal, and not the frequency itself..

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: is this the same as http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261347/change-pwm-frequency ?